# Change a custom view class property from a ViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view that draws a circle on the screen. it have a property of color.

That color is the color of the circle.

I have another ViewController that is the parent of that view and owns another subview - UISegmentControl.

My wish is to change the color property and the view color when i click a segment button.
The app runs with no errors and the segment action works (as i see in the NSLog).

So what am i missing here?
(I know i probably could add the segment to the other view, but lets say i cant)

here is the loadView of the my viewcontroller:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    self.segment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"red",@"blue",@"green"]];
//this is my costumed view:
    BNRHypnosisView *backgroundView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc]init];
    self.view = backgroundView;

    CGRect frame = self.segment.frame;
    CGRect window = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    frame.origin.x = (window.size.width-frame.size.width) /2.0;
    frame.origin.y = window.size.height -100;

    self.segment.frame = frame;
    [self.segment addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:self.segment];

}
-(void)action:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was touched",self);
    BNRHypnosisView *backgroundView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc]init];
    backgroundView.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't re-create a new view, just set the property on your existing view:

```
-(void)action:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was touched",self);
    BNRHypnosisView *backgroundView = (BNRHypnosisView*)self.view;
    backgroundView.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

As a side note, I would call `setNeedsDisplay` inside the view's `setCircleColor:` instead. This keeps the implementation detail of "changing the circle color needs to redraw the view" inside your `BNRHypnosisView` class, which is better encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks, thats helped.
about the encapsulation, if u mean change the target to the view's object and to implement that selector over there - did it and that worked.
Calling only setNeedsDisplay there - cant see how that helps though

Answer (score 1):

You have the view, but why do you allocate it again. Do you have the view added to the viewcontroller's view. If you want to add the view and then change the color property then do it like this,

```
-(void)action:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@ was touched",self);
    BNRHypnosisView *backgroundView = [[BNRHypnosisView alloc]init];
    backgroundView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview: backgroundView];
    backgroundView.circleColor = [UIColor redColor];

}
```